# Обработка EXE файл в браузере(в Python-сервере)

Tags: браузер, exe

Модераторы не удаляйте пожалуйста
Как запустить или отобразить(или обработоть на сервере и отобразить в браузере) exe файл в браузере? Был ответ:

> При выполнении команды os.system "PATH/TO/EXE.EXE" в Python-сервере
>   будет исполняться исполняемый файл и вывод из stdout попадает на
>   страницу. Вроде, всё просто и легко выполняемо!

***stdout попадает на страницу***

Расскажите поподробнее(stdout попадает на страницу), нужен специальный код в exe файле для вывода в браузер, любой файл не подойдет? Напишите пример кода пожалуйста именно этого примера(os.system "PATH/TO/EXE.EXE",будет исполняться исполняемый файл и вывод из stdout попадает на страницу)

Comment: Если нужно чтобы исполняемый файл выводил данные на страницу, смотрите в строну CGI

Comment: напишите пожалуйста пример вывода(желательно графики, а не текста) или ссылку на готовый пример